# recommended way to return multiple variables from math-crunching AS3 function?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm new to Actionscript programming. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to return multiple variables, each having a different data type, from a function. For example, if a function needs to return variable aa ( a string) and variable bb (a number).

The function I'm using just crunches a lot of math, and doesn't relate to an object in a GUI. One method I got from a Google search used an Object, but as (I think) this requires me to create a class, I wondered if there was a simpler way. Since an array can hold elements of different data types, perhaps this is a simpler approach (?).

Here's an example mxml and AS3 file taken from "Flash Builder 4 and Flex 4 Bible" by David Gassner.

file: Calculator.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
  xmlns:components="components.*">
  <fx:Script source="calculator.as"/>
  <s:Panel title="Calculator" horizontalCenter="0" top="20">
    <s:layout>
      <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>
    <mx:Form>
      <components:ButtonTile id="input" 
        select="selectHandler(event)" 
        calculate="calculateHandler(event)"/>
      <mx:FormItem label="Entry:">
        <s:TextInput text="{currentInput}" editable="false" width="80"/>
      </mx:FormItem>
      <mx:FormItem label="Total:">
        <s:TextInput text="{currentResult}" editable="false" width="80"/>
      </mx:FormItem>   
    </mx:Form>
```

file: calculator.as

```
//ActionScript code for Calculator.mxml
[Bindable]
private var currentResult:Number=0;
[Bindable]
private var currentInput:String="";

private function calculateHandler(event:Event):void
{
  currentResult += Number(currentInput);
  currentInput="";
}
private function selectHandler(event:TextEvent):void
{
  currentInput += event.text;
}
```

Could someone illustrate how to modify one of the functions in calculator.as, just as an example how to return two values, where one is a number and the other a string? Is there an obvious best-way to do this, or, what would be the pros/cons of different approaches? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just simply return an `Object` which is `dynamic` and thus lets you define values on the fly, like this:

```
return {something: "string", another: 18};
```

Or:

```
var obj:Object = {};

obj.something = "string";
obj.another = 18;

return obj;
```

But in my opinion this is really poor practice (especially if your function is to return the same sets of information with new values).

I'd take this route:

You can create your own class that holds various properties. From there you can return an instance of this object with the properties defined as you wish.

Example:
This would be in an external file called `CollisionData.as`

```
package
{
    public class CollisionData
    {
        public var x:Number = 0;       // X coordinate of the collision
        public var y:Number = 0;       // Y coordinate of the collision
        public var angle:Number = 0;   // Collision angle
    }
}
```

And your function could be:

```
function calculate():CollisionData
{
    var col:CollisionData = new CollisionData();

    // determine collision details
    col.x = 115;
    col.y = 62;
    col.angle = 0.345;

    return col;
}
```

Then you can create your own collision data based off the result:

```
var myCollision:CollisionData = calculate();
```

And fetch the details:

```
trace(
    myCollision.x,
    myCollision.y,
    myCollision.angle
);
```

Comment: Thanks Marty! Regarding your last recommendation, could you help me digest the various pieces of your example by showing which snippets go in the .as file and which would go in the .mxml file? What would the completed two files look like? (still missing the big picture how to put everything together)

Comment: See edit regarding how to put `CollisionData` in it's own file. The easiest way to get your head around this is that every `class` requires it's own external .as file.

Comment: ggkmath: if you really need to crunch many numbers, you can avoid creation of object on each call. Use static object to return data - but you have to pull data from it before it will be overwritten on next call. Less memory thrashing -> much faster executon.

Comment: Thanks alxx, less memory and faster is important. Could you give an example (in more detail) in a separate answer?

Comment: Thanks Marty for your last edits. Why not just avoid defining a class and simply define a standalone function that returns an array with the required variables as elements of the array? Is there a downside to doing this?

Comment: The idea behind creating a class is that when you come back to your code down the track you'll know what to expect from functions that use this set of data. Also you'll get errors if you make typos on the information which stops a lot of problems from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create class, this should work for you:

```
public function calculate():Object
{
    return {valueA: "string", valueB: 1};
}
```

Comment: Sure, class will make it more clear what this return object represents and how to treat it

Comment: Would this execute faster than creating a Class and object as above?

Comment: I think it's the same, but you must be clear about your intensions, besides, if you create a class, I will help other developers, who might support your code in the future, to easier understand what do you return. If you return Object - it's unclear, if you return some UserDetails it will make more sense.